# How can I change the Visual Studio Code theme?

Tags: java, html, visual-studio-code

I'm not digging the whole default theme and stuff. I looked in the settings and can't seem to find a way to change it.

Comment: If you're using windows then `ctrl+shift+p` -> `Preferences: Color theme`. Just so you know, a single google search yields endless results for how to do this. Why bloat the site with questions that already have tons of answers easily available to you?

Comment: Surely there are plenty of duplicates?? This is more like using Stack Overflow as a human search engine or a help desk. What is the canonical question? Why isn't there even an attempt to find it instead of answering as if it hasn't been asked before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the default theme, visit:

*Settings* → *Color Theme* → *Select Theme*

[image]

Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

[image]

And select the theme you want to apply.

You can download new themes from the extensions panel on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Extensions (Ctrl-Shift-X) then click on your theme in the sidebar then click "Set Colour Theme" below the title and description.